# ¿Cómo eliminar clave y valor en un json con java?

Tags: java, json

tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Estoy trabajando con un json pero necesito retirar una clave y valor, cuando el valor es vacío.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que contribuyenteEspecial ya no se tome en cuenta. Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte de alguna libería como Gson o Jackson.

Por ejemplo con Gson, si pasas ese Json a un objeto de tipo Gson, podrías eliminar dicha clave con

```
jsonObj.getAsJsonObject("infoFactora").remove("contribuyenteEspecial");
```

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente se elimina, pero ¿cómo puedo pasar el objeto tipo gson nuevamente al json?

Comment: Mira la librería de Gson:   https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/. Ahí vienen ejemplos de como convertir objetos a json y viceversa. Con gson.toJson(json) creo que te valdría

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion podria ser pasar el json por un Map, recorrerlo y eliminar los que se encuentren vacios, algo asi:

```
String json = "{'clave1': 'hola', 'clave2': '', 'clave3': 'valor', 'clave4': null}"; 
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType(); 
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type); 

for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = data.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) { 
    Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next(); 
    if (entry.getValue() == null || entry.getValue() == "") { 
     it.remove(); 
    } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) { 
     if (((ArrayList<?>) entry.getValue()).isEmpty()) { 
      it.remove(); 
     } 
    } 
} 

json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data); 
System.out.println(json);
```